# How to remove the gap between columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple struture on BootStrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 blue-section" ><p>Some content</p></div>
     <div class="col-md-4 red-section"><p>Some content</p></div>
     <div class="col-md-4 green-section"><p>Some Content</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS custom file is:

```
.container{ width:100%;}
.row{ background-color:#000;}

.blue-section{background-color:blue;}
.red-section{background-color:red;}
.green-section{background-color:green;}
```

When I resize the page and the columns stack on each other there is a gap between them and a space after the last with the same height of the previous gaps.
How can I remove those gaps? Is on the `.row`or is on the `.col-*-*`?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the same look for smaller devices also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gaps are caused by the `margin-bottom` on the `p` tags. to remove `margin-bottom` from the last element inside of `col-md-4` see the last line in the  following CSS (I've added extra paragraphs to demonstrate only the last element is targetted):

```css
.container{ width:100%;}
.row{ background-color:#000;}

.blue-section{background-color:blue;}
.red-section{background-color:red;}
.green-section{background-color:green;}

.col-md-4 > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 blue-section">
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 red-section">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 green-section">
      <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll want to scope that last line correctly too...

Answer (score 0):

to remove gab from divs you need to add p {margin:0}

Please See this link     [`demo`  ]     https://jsfiddle.net/k1jh1bu2/1/